# Tesseract (Swedish language) can't recognize special characters like @, § etc

Tags: tesseract

I use Tesseract version 4 (swedish).
When interpreting images, it can never recognize some special characters like @, § etc.
For example, if I have xxx@gmail.com, it interprets xxxdgmail.com
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try combining with `eng` language -- or one that supports your special characters -- such as `-l swe+eng` or `-l eng+swe`

Comment: Thank you ! How does this affect performance? What is difference between swe+eng or eng+swe?

Comment: The dominant language appears first.